# How to retrain AdaBoostClassifier with new data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, adaboost

**Scenario:** Today I trained AdaBoostClassifier with past 1 week data and next week needs to train with new 1 week data to the existing trained classifier.

For Randomforest I'm using *warm_start=True*. where AdaBoostClassifier not supported directly.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to perform incremental learning. In sklearn, it is not possible to perform it using AdaBoost.

The algorithms that have implemented incremental learning are listed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning). You will notice these algorithms implement the method `partial_fit()`.

If you want to keep using the AdaBoostClassifier, you should retrain the model using all the data (the past 1 week and the new 1 week).

Comment: Thank you Noki for response. This is what I want.